# Spotify Apps Api - Adding playlist to users library (i.e. subscribing to it)

Tags: api, spotify

Is there an official way of adding a playlist to the user's library?

This code snippet seems to work:

```
    sp.core.library.addPlaylist('spotify:uri')
```

But is not documented nor a public API.

Comment: You should not do this as sp.core is not intended for be used directly. The solution by Geraud is the one that are is the right.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution :

```
var playlist = m.Playlist.fromURI('');
playlist.subscribed = true;
```

Tested

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#art"+id+" #savePlaylist").live('click',function(e){
var myAwesomePlaylist = new m.Playlist(album.artist.name + " - " + pl.name);
$.each(pl.data.all(),function(i,track){
    myAwesomePlaylist.add(track);
});
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Where $("#art"+id+" #savePlaylist") is my button
And pl the visible playlist...

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 

I think there is a difference between "cloning" a playlist (what your code does) and "subscribing" to another user's playlist thereby maintaining the reference (which the unofficial "snippet" does), isn't there? I might be wrong, tho'.

Comment: Found this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791293/spotify-app-api-playlist-subscribe

Comment: Yes, but that only indicates, if the current use *has* subscribed, it does not actively subscribe him :)

Comment: No, its working, I put the answer below